# Check for empty object and return boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `AddContactForm` form that allows the user to add `contacts`.

When the user fills in the `conactNumber`- `onBlur` it checks if this `conactNumber` already exists.

How can I make The `CheckIfContactExists` function returns either `true` or `false` instead of the promise object?

Please note that I can't change the returned value from the api, it only return a `contact` object.

```
export default class AddContactForm extends Component {
  state = {
   ...
  };

  checkContact = () => {
    const { contactNumber } = this.state.newContactInfo;
    CheckIfContactExists(contactNumber); //return promise
  };

 render() {
   ...
    return (  
       ...
   );
  }
}

const CheckIfContactExists = async searchString => {
  const { data: contactsInfo } = await axios.get(`api/Contacts/SearchContact?contactNum=${searchString}`);
};
```

Comment: you can't, that's the thing with asynchronous calls they return promise, you can make it so promise resovles into boolean, but it will still be a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make it return just a boolean since it's an asynchronous operation. You could  make the `checkContact` function `async` as well and `await` it.

**Example**

```
export default class AddContactForm extends Component {
  state = {
   // ...
  };

  checkContact = async () => {
    const { contactNumber } = this.state.newContactInfo;
    const contactInfo = await CheckIfContactExists(contactNumber);

    this.setState({
      contactNumberTaken: Object.keys(contactInfo).length !== 0
    });
  };

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but `Boolean(contactsInfo)` will always result `true`, An object that doesn't have any properties assigned is not considered "empty".

Comment: @user3378165 That's true. I updated the answer with a check to see if it's an empty object that was returned.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of async await in checkContact just like you did for `CheckIfContactExists`. Also return the boolean result from `CheckIfContactExits` method

```
export default class AddContactForm extends Component {
  state = {
   ...
  };

  checkContact = async () => {
    const { contactNumber } = this.state.newContactInfo;
    try {
      const res = await CheckIfContactExists(contactNumber); 
      return res;
    } catch (e) {
       console.log('Error', error);
    }
  };

 render() {
   ...
    return (  
       ...
   );
  }
}

const CheckIfContactExists = async searchString => {
  const { data: contactsInfo } = await axios.get(`api/Contacts/SearchContact?contactNum=${searchString}`);
  if (Object.keys(contactsInfo).length > 0) {
     return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but `if (contactsInfo)` will always result `true`, An object that doesn't have any properties assigned is not considered "empty".

Comment: In that case you could simply check for size of object keys. My assumption when I wrote the answer was that the contactsInfo is returned undefined or null if not found